# Missing dotnet.exe in Azure WebJob

Tags: .net, azure, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core Console App as an Azure WebJob. All files etc. are getting copied to the right directories but my console app its output is a .dll, so it requires `dotnet.exe` to start.

I've added a run.cmd file with the single command: `dotnet QbiSync.dll`.
But the output is the following, it can't seem to find dotnet.exe:

```
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: INFO] 
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\QbiSync\x4jkoxww.vy4>dotnet QbiSync.dll 
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: ERR ] 'dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: ERR ] operable program or batch file.
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
[11/14/2016 13:15:29 > 4741da: SYS INFO] Process went down, waiting for 60 seconds
```

Opening up a Console window using Kudu or in the Azure Portal and calling `dotnet.exe` both works fine. I've also tried hardlinks like:

- `"D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" QbiSync.dll`
- `"\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" QbiSync.dll`

But they also give errors like:

```
[11/14/2016 13:59:29 > 4741da: ERR ] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[11/14/2016 13:59:29 > 4741da: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\QbiSync\hzlkzj1q.0jt>"D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe" QbiSync.dll
```

Even though the dotnet.exe is actually located there.

**Update**:

Possibly related is that the source used `@echo off` at the start of the script. But this is also a "command" that doesn't seem to be accepted.

```
[11/14/2016 12:37:57 > 4741da: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\QbiSync\3n44nly1.ucq>@echo off 
[11/14/2016 12:37:57 > 4741da: INFO] 
[11/14/2016 12:37:57 > 4741da: ERR ] '@echo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

**Sources used:**

- https://blog.decayingcode.com/post/creating-.net-core-console-webjobs-on-an-asp.net-core-azure-webapp/

Comment: What happens if you try running your run.cmd manually from Kudu Console?

Comment: As a quick test, I tried creating a continuous WebJob with a run.cmd that just has `dotnet.exe QbiSync.dll` (without having the dll). It failed with `The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\DotNetContJob\tgq45gw1.kb2\QbiSync.dll'`, which means it successfully launched dotnet.exe and only failed because the dll is not there. Can you try this same test to isolate?

Comment: @DavidEbbo It successfully starts and has the expected output using the kudu console with `D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\QbiSync\jf0yv53s.i3c>run.cmd`. I'll check your second comment in a few minutes.

Comment: @DavidEbbo Same error, dotnet.exe can't be found. Does it also use the WindowsScriptHost in your case? `SYS INFO]  Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'`

Comment: `[11/14/2016 15:33:51 > e06c64: SYS INFO] Run script 'run.cmd' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[11/14/2016 15:33:51 > e06c64: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[11/14/2016 15:33:51 > e06c64: INFO] 
[11/14/2016 15:33:51 > e06c64: INFO] D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\DotNetContJob\vocvjalz.qbl>dotnet.exe QbiSync.dll 
[11/14/2016 15:33:51 > e06c64: ERR ] The application to execute does not exist: 'D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\DotNetContJob\vocvjalz.qbl\QbiSync.dll'`

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks, it seems there is more going on than just an issue with dotnet.exe. I've edited the post to tell that `@echo off` is also not being accepted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128076/discussion-between-david-ebbo-and-raymen).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue is that your `run.cmd` uses UTF-8 with [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (byte order marks), which in some cases causes the script engine to misbehave. The fix is to not have the BOM.

There is a mention of this on the wiki (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs), but granted it's easy to miss.

Comment: I am trying to run a web job from an HTTP Client. The file is a ZIP file . and contains a java class and bat file to run that java class. This runs okay when i do from POSTMAN. But when i use HTTP client, i get the following error always " '---i-NPsGbTVUpaP0CeJxMQVrHoDHvaxo3' is not recognized as an internal or external command" - Please help

Comment: @Jagaran if it only happen from some clients, it is likely unrelated. Please ask a new question

Comment: No any HTTP Client i am using in java, it is the same. it works in CURL or loading from web console. My sample code below

Comment: No any HTTP Client i am using in java, it is the same. it works in CURL or loading from web console. My sample code below. I am using uni restHttpResponse<InputStream> jsonResponse = Unirest.put("https://azurewebjobtestbrms.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/TestJOb")    .basicAuth("$AzureWebJobTestBRMS","XXX".header("Content-Disposition","attachement; filename=acvbgth.bat").header("Content-Type","zip").field("file", new  ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream("AzureWebJob.zip")) ,ContentType.create("application/zip"),"AzureWebJob.zip").asBinary();

Comment: Do you have any sample Java based HTTP Client where I can publish Azure Web Job? I have tried all Java REST clients. May be i am doing something wrong. The error I get in Azure console is '---i-NPsGbTVUpaP0CeJxMQVrHoDHvaxo3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[08/25/2017 09:30:22 > e7f683: ERR ] operable program or batch file.

Comment: I feel Content type = applciation /zip is not happening correctly when using java. Please help us

Comment: This question has nothing to do with what you're describing. You need to start a new question.

Comment: Done, please answer that sir

Comment: For me I managed to have the run.cmd run fine, only by adding `@echo off` at the beginning of the file, followed by a blank line. I the console, it fails on the echo but then it can execute dotnet xxxxx.dll

Answer (score 3):

In my experience the simplest way to get a .NET Core Console App running within the context of an Azure WebJob is to create a self-contained `.exe`.

You can do this with the following command:

```
dotnet publish -r win10-x64 -c Release
```

> **Note** that the above command produces a different output than a `Right-click > Publish` action.

This will create a folder called `win10-x64` within the `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0` directory of your console app. Inside of the `win10-x64` directory is another directory called `publish`.

> Simply compress the `...bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\win10-x64\publish` folder and upload as a new WebJob.

The trigger mechanism will detect the `.exe` and run the code within the console app.

Comment: You can also right click the project, click Publish, and create a Folder profile. Then publishing generates the exe and all the folders you mentioned. Zip up the publish folder and it's good to go as a web job.